# Extract values from large rasterstack, R

Tags: r, extract, large-datasets, rasterstack

I have a large `rasterstack` of about 500 objects. I want to sample easch object with the use of a `SpatialPointDataframe` and then export the results as file`.csv`. I have tried the following but within the `SpatialPointDataframe` I get a large matrix of the extracted values and I can not export it. It might be something basic, but I can not see it.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
points$twsx<-extract(largerasterstack,points)
writeOGR(obj=points, dsn=".", layer="extracted", driver="ESRI Shapefile") 

Error in writeOGR(obj = points, dsn = ".", layer = "extracted", driver = "ESRI Shapefile") : 
  Can't convert columns of class: matrix; column names: twsx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `cbind` to add the returned matrix from a stack-point overlay as multiple columns to your point data frame:

```
> extract(s,spd)
      layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
 [1,]     626     626     626
 [2,]     554     554     554
...
> spd = cbind(spd, extract(s,spd))
> writeOGR(spd,"/tmp","foo","ESRI Shapefile")
>
```